# What's the proper way to adjust the height of an html element to fill the remaining space between fixed header and footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website that should be able to display photos and other contents as large as possible. I'm aiming to have a fixed-sized header and footer (let's say 40px height for each) and I want a `<div>` Element to fill all the space in between (i.e. height 100% of viewport minus 80px). I just want maximum content space on all screens, no scrolling.

```
 +---------------------+
 | Header (40px)       |
 +---------------------+
 |                     |
 | Dynamic (100%-80px) |
 |                     |
 |                     |
 +---------------------+
 | Footer (40px)       |
 +---------------------+
```

What is the proper way to do this? Is this even possible with plain css or will javascript be required?

Comment: try using `calc(100% - 80px);` or absolute positioning (set only the `top` and the `bottom` without setting the `height`).

Answer (score 0):

Using the box model with known height for header and footer it can esily be achieved.

You can choose box-model render via `box-sizing`.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YE7nk/)**

---

other possibilitie is to use display:table; **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eYJ6A/1/)**

Here , `footer` will be pushed down if too much content to sit in middle.

---

Other possibilities are `display:flex` or a technique similar to fausses-column where you use `body` `background` and set no border nor backgrounds to middle container. Footer remains down in absolute or fixed position.

---

Demos based on HTML:

```
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the css `height:calc(100%-80px)` will only work in new browsers (though that is quite a large market share)

There are easier solutions such as making your header and footer fixed and padding your content by the height of the header and footer to prevent the content being hidden behind the header and footer.

Example in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/4YwYw/1)

CSS:

```
body{
 background-color:grey;  
 padding: 50px 0;     
 margin: 0px;
}
header {
 position:fixed;
 height:40px;
 width:100%;
 top:0px;
 background-color:red;
}
footer {
 position:fixed;
 height:40px;
 width:100%;
 bottom:0px;
 background-color:red;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    Header
</header>
<div>
    Contents: Bla Bla Bla
</div>
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
```

This will also allow for scrolling content automatically if it extend past the height of the window